# C++: what is special about punning character arrays according to the standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have this memory that arrays of `char` are the only safely punnable types in C++ according to the standard. That is, if you have a `char*` pointer to the first element of an appropriately aligned and sized array of `char`, it's safe to `reinterpret_cast<T*>` that pointer, but would not be safe for e.g. `uint8_t` according to the standard.

However, I can't find this anywhere in the current draft standard. Am I misremembering? Did this change for C++17? Can somebody quote the relevant parts of the standard?

Comment: You are. There is nothing special about `char` arrays whatsoever. There's something special about `char` *pointers*.

Comment: @n.m. Other way around (sort of)... there's nothing special about char pointers, however `char` lvalues are special (in terms of strict aliasing).

Comment: @M.M right but how are you going to obtain these lvalues? Oh I think you can use references. Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a strict aliasing violation to use an expression of type `T` to read or write an array of `char` (if `T` is not one of the exceptions in the rule).

Strict aliasing isn't a two-way street: you can use a `char` expression to access a `T`, but not vice versa.

The section is [basic.lval]/10 in the C++14 standard. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/1505939)  for the full text of it.

Further, the standard says that `uint8_t` is a typedef for another type. All known implementations make it a typedef for `char` or `unsigned char`.

Some people have recommended that the standard explicitly specify `uint8_t` be a character type.  That would also solve problems like `uint8_t x = 'a'; cout << x;` not being well-defined.

Comment: Thanks, I think the exception for `char` in the strict aliasing rule ([draft standard link](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#lval-8)) is what I was thinking of.

Comment: Though how does this interact with things like `std::aligned_storage`? Surely there's some standards-safe way to take an array of `char` and turn it into a `T*`? Or is this only through blessed types like `std::aligned_storage`?

Comment: @jacobsa you use placement-new to create objects in the aligned storage, or char array . Then the area is considered to be an object of the created type, and no longer an object of the aligned storage class etc.

Comment: Thanks. So let's say you use `mmap` to get a page from the OS as a `void*`, and want to treat it as a zeroed array of some struct type. What's the standards-compliant way to do this? Do you need to use placement new for each element of the array? Is the compiler likely to optimize this away for a POD struct?

Comment: @jacobsa You can placement-new the entire array and yes it ought to be a no-op.

Comment: The standard doesn't cover the process of objects being created outside of user C++ code . In practice it's likely to work as the compiler can't know that objects weren't correctly created